# adding `ScrollView` to my list it throws error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a list of images to show to the user. to have it scrollable i added `ScrollView` but then when i add `ScrollView` to my list it throws this error:

[image]

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide some code if you want any help with that

Comment: which part of the code is needed?

Comment: I think putting your whole component file is probably necessary.